# PHP For loop, Print specifc no of times

Tags: php

I want to loop and echo images specific value, I have a db value e.g 100, but i want to echo only 96 images only not more than that. Also whatever the value from DB and loop should print the exact times not exceeding 96(which is fixed)

```
$check = "SELECT white FROM balloons";
$rs = mysqli_query($con,$check);
if(mysqli_num_rows($rs)==1)
{
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rs);
$g=$row['white']; //eg 2,

for($imagecount=0;$imagecount>$g;$imagecount++) {
echo '<img src="img/whiteB.png" class="w_over" />';
}
}
```

Comment: You can do it using loop break statement.

Comment: Limit your query instead. `SELECT white FROM balloons LIMIT 96;`.

Comment: white itself is a number.... there are not n numbers of rows, there it ONE row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd change

```
for($imagecount=0;$imagecount>$g;$imagecount++) {
```

to

```
for($imagecount=0;$imagecount<=min($g,96);$imagecount++) {
```

Pls. note that the 2nd param in for needs to inverted (loop **while** condition is true)

Answer (score 2):

```
for ($i=0; $i < min($g, 96); $i++) {
  echo '<img src="img/whiteB.png" class="w_over" />';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If i get your question correctly you just need to change your line,

```
$g=$row['white'];
```

to:

```
$g = ($row['white'] < 96) ? $row['white'] : 96;
```

**Side Note**:

```
 for($imagecount = 0; $imagecount < $g; $imagecount++) //Should be less then
                                  ^
```

Answer (score 0):

Error in for loop condition!

change for loop head:

```
for($imagecount=0;$imagecount<$g;$imagecount++)
```